# Shopware 6: Twig files not loaded when using sw_include

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, shopware

currently I'm struggeling with my theme for Shopwre 6.
In Version 6.2.2 my theme breaks and won't load any includes twig files.

Following code is in my base.html.twig file of my theme.

```
{% block base_header %}
    <header class="header-main">
        {% block base_header_inner %}
            <div class="container">
                {% sw_include '@Themename/storefront/layout/header/header.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </header>
{% endblock %}
```

With this notation nothing loads. Replacing sw_extends with extends, loads the file.

In Version 6.1.6 it was working, but not in current 6.2.2. In my theme.json my view looks the following:

```
"views": [
     "@Storefront",
     "@Plugins",
     "@Themename"
  ],
```

Thanks for your help and advice.

Marcus

Comment: You say replacing sw_extends with extends will load the file. In the code you shared there is neither a sw_extend nor an extend statement. Could you clarify on that?

Comment: Hi, oh, that is my mistake. Sorry, I mean of course sw_include and include. I'm sorry, for this wrong post of mine. As shopware writes in their documentation https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/storefront/templates#page-templates it should used for inheritance. But it does not work on my environment.

Comment: Thanks for your question! Your code just helped me find another error I had in my own theme where I had to debug a line trying to `{% sw_include '@Storefront/layout/footer/filename.html.twig' %}` (probably written down mistakenly from a tutorial, or is that supposed to work as well?) When using the actual `@ThemeName/storefront/...` everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested a little bit and It seems that this is a naming conflict. Because the name of the custom `layout/header/header.html.twig` is the same as in the core theme it gets overwritten and included at the same time. When I create a file with the same name under the same directory it will override the core file by default. And in the example it's also included by another custom template. However when I rename it to e.g. "custom-header" and include it as "custom-header" it works.

When the custom theme's "header.html.twig" is extending the core "header.html.twig" it would also be possible to not include this at all. Because the `base_header` block in the example above looks basically the same in the core template. The header can be overwritten by adding a `layout/header/header.html.twig` in the custom theme. The include of the header itself is already happening in the core "base.html.twig"